# In Python, how can I get part of docx document?

Tags: python-3.x, docx

I would like to get part of docx document ( for example, 10% of all content) with Python 3. How I can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I'll try to combine them to achieve exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A good way to interact with .docx files in python is the [docx2txt module](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt).

If you have pip installed you can open your terminal and run:

```
pip install docx2txt
```

Once you have the docx module you can run:

```
import docx2txt
```

You can then return the text in the document and filter only the parts you want. The contents of *filename.docx* is stored as a string in the variable **text.**

```
text = docx2txt.process("filename.docx")
print(text)
```

It is now possible to manipulate that string using some basic built-functions. The code snippet below prints the results of **text**, returns the length using the **len()** function, and slices the string to about 10% by creating a substring.

```
len(text)
print(len(text))  # returns 1000 for my sample document

text = text[1:100]
print(text)  # returns 10% of the string
```

My full code for this example is below. I hope this is helpful!

```
import docx2txt

text = docx2txt.process("/home/jared/test.docx")
print(text)

len(text)
print(len(text))  # returns 1000 for my sample document

text = text[1:100]
print(text)  # returns 10% of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something line this:

```
from math import floor

def docx(file, percent):
  text = []
  lines = sum(1 for line in open(file))
  #print("File has {0} lines".format(lines))
  no = floor((lines * percent / 100))
  #print('Rounded to ', no)
  limit = 0
  with open(file) as f:
    for l in f:
      text.append(l)
      limit += 1
      if limit == no:
        break
  return text
```

To test it try:

```
print(docx('example.docx', 10))
```